# Is there anything in seaborn that would help me print the names better?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am trying to visualize multiple data-frames together using bar-plot but I am facing problems printing the names of the categories as they get jumbled together. What can I do to make it print correctly?

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
plt.subplot(131)
plt.title('Primary Percentage Contribution')
sns.barplot(y = primary_precentage.index, x = primary_precentage['Primary 
Percentage Contribution'])

plt.subplot(132)
plt.title('Secondary Percentage Contribution')
sns.barplot(y = secondary_percentage.index, x = 
secondary_percentage['Secondary Percentage Contribution'])

plt.subplot(133)
plt.title('Tertiary Percentage Contribution')
sns.barplot(y = tertiary_percentage.index, 
x=tertiary_percentage['Tertiary Percentage Contribution'])
```

I want the names of the categories to be printed in a clean way without them getting overlapped.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow ! Have a look at [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then edit your question with maybe a sample of your data, a plot with what your have wrong ...

Comment: This is fairly standard stuff, matplotlib is an alternative approach. Personally I export to ggplot2 (R) either directly or via the rpy2 library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly the outcome expected, but you can try adding this to your code:

```py
plt.tight_layout()
```

As per the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html):

> > Automatically adjust subplot parameters to give specified padding.